# É indiferente usar SQL Server ou MySQL com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou montando um projeto médio e irei modelar o banco, para então criar as tabelas, as *views*, as *procedures* além do próprio banco é claro. Eu iria criar tudo com o MySQL, porém por já mexer com SQL Server, achei que poderia utilizar o mesmo ao invés do MySQL.

Tudo o que eu posso fazer com PHP + MySQL conseguirei também com PHP + SQL Server?

Com os prós e contras que cada linguagem de banco teria ao se usar com PHP, vale a pena usar o SQL Server que é um banco com mais recursos, ou usar o MySQL mesmo, que é mais usado com PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O básico sim, é tudo igual, mas saiu do "arroz com feijão" já muda tudo. Muda a sintaxe dos comandos SQL (não profundamente, mas de forma incompatível em vários detalhes), e muda principalmente o que pode ser configurado no banco de dados e as formas de otimização diversas.

Dá para fazer o mesmo modelo se encaixar "bem", mas isso é obtido com a técnica do "mínimo denominador comum" que sempre fará a aplicação ficar um pouco a desejar. Em alguns casos pode não ser um grande problema, em outros pode ser um enorme. Tem vários recursos que só são encontrados em um deles, mas também tem vários que não iguaizinhos em ambos.

Por isso acho uma bobagem a pessoa que adora PDO, Entity Framework e outras coisas do tipo, pelo motivo que eles abstraem o banco de dados e permitem trocar o fornecedor depois. Se fosse simples assim eu adoraria, mas na prática se for fazer isso mesmo, a aplicação sofrerá. Por sorte a maioria acaba "abstraindo" o banco de dados mas otimiza para um só e nunca muda (que é o oposto do que ela pensava que ia fazer, e mostra que ela não tem ideia do que está fazendo). **Essa é uma das maiores mentiras contadas na computação**.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você acha que vale mais a pena usar com mysql mesmo? Porque se eu fosse usar com o Sql Server, teria que usar com o PDO. Mas se eu optar pelo mysql, não usarei PDO, mas sim o mysqli. Acredito que essa é a única dúvida que persiste antes da minha escolha.

Comment: Aí não sei dizer, cada caso é um caso, depende do projeto, da pessoa que vai trabalhar e outros fatores específicos. Posso estar enganado mas não sei se precisa do PDO para usar o SQL Server. Eu sempre evito o PDO.

Comment: Mas, o PDO não foi implementado para, literalmente, ligar o "pouco me importa qual DB seja"? Tanto que ainda vem Doctrine, entre outras libraries e Patterns??

Comment: Tem um driver especifico para [SQL Server](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) o sqlsrv que substitui o antigo mssql.

Comment: sim não precisa. Existem outros modos que já usei. Porém se fosse com sql server, eu acho que usaria o PDO. Mas pq você evita o PDO bigown?

Comment: Mas rray. Se não me engano, esse driver contém bem menos funções que a nativa do mysql.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino isso é a promessa, e os incautos caem nela. Funciona? Claro. É bom, não. Serve pra muita gente? Sim.

Comment: @DiChrist O PDO é uma camada extra cuja única vantagem real é fazer algo que é impossível fazer bem feito. Acho que tem pergunta sobre isso aqui. Preciso ver uma que tem respostas boas. E por acaso o PDO faz como para acessar o SQL Server? Ele tem driver próprio maravilhoso? Acho que não. Mas está chegando no ponto do que coloquei na resposta. Tem inúmeras diferenças. O PDO não faz milagre, ele não usa o máximo denominador comum, ele usa o mínimo.

Comment: @DiChrist seria a falta de uma função por exemplo de pegar o id inserido(`mysqli_insert_id()`)? tem algum exemplo?

Comment: mysqli_connect_errno(), mysqli_refresh(),  mysqli_fetch_assoc()  são algumas delas rray. Não lembro todas e se não em engano, não há correspondentes exatos para essas funções.